# Crontab for every Thursday

Tags: cron

I'm trying to schedule a restart function every THURSDAY at 11:55pm!

```
55 23 * * * /usr/html/scheduler/restart.sh > /usr/html/scheduler/file.log
```

This is what the developer made but it's rescheduling on Monday or Tuesday. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last asterisk should be replaced with 4 (day of week - Thursday) as following: 55 23 * * 4.

u can also use the following tool which makes your life easier when setting up a new crobjob - https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Thanks. So what does `55 23 * * *` stand for?

Comment: run every day at 11:55PM @ElaineByene